# How to implement customized cache in C# UWP application

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, uwp

I have a web service (**ItemWebService**) which calls an API and get a list of items (**productList**). This service is called from a **UWP application**.

Requirements are:

- Cache the list of products for a certain time period (eg: 1 hour) and return the cached list **if available** and **not timed out** when called the `GetProductListAsync()`.
- No need to cache each hour, because this process is going to be a very rare process and the UWP application is run across multiple devices in an organisation. Therefore if set an **interval** to cache, the API would get hundreds of requests at the same time each hour.
- Whenever a new item is added to the product list from method `AddProductAsync(AddProductRequest addProductRequest )`, the cache should be refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To meet the above requirements, a customized cache was implemented in the **ItemWebService**.

```
using NodaTime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyNamespace.Products
{
    public class ItemWebService : IItemService
    {
        private readonly IApiRestClient _restClient;
        private readonly string _serviceUrl = "api/products";
        private static IEnumerable<ProductListItem> _cachedProductist = null;
        private readonly IClock _clock;
        private readonly Duration _productlistValidFor = Duration.FromHours(1); // Set the timeout
        private static Instant _lastUpdate = Instant.MinValue;


        public ItemWebService (IApiRestClient restClient)
        {
            _restClient = restClient;
            _clock = SystemClock.Instance; // using NodaTime
        }

        public async Task AddProductAsync(AddProductRequest addProductRequest)
        {
            await _restClient.Put($"{_serviceUrl}/add", addProductRequest);

            // Expire cache manually to update product list on next call
            _lastUpdate = _clock.GetCurrentInstant() - _productlistValidFor ;
        }

        public async Task<IObservable<ProductListItem>> GetProductListAsync()
        {
            if (_cachedProductist == null || (_lastUpdate + _productlistValidFor) < _clock.GetCurrentInstant())
            {
                _cachedProductist = await _restClient.Get<IEnumerable<ProductListItem>>($"{_serviceUrl}/productList");

                // Update the last updated time
                _lastUpdate = _clock.GetCurrentInstant();
            }
            return _cachedProductist.ToObservable();
        }
    }
}
```

With this implementation I was able to avoid setting an **interval** which would have cause hundreds of API calls(because there are hundreds of devices running the same app) to refresh cache each hour.

Now, whenever the device running the UWP app requests a list of products, the service would check if cache exists and not expired on that device and calls the server to refresh cache if necessary.